# Referencing outputs of a nested stack Error: "the attribute in Fn::ImportValue must not depend on any resources"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation template in which I'm creating a CodeBuild project and a nested stack of VPC-related resources.  Here's an excerpt:

```
Resources:
  VpcStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/foo-bar/vpc/vpc.template.json
  CustomCodeBuild:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
    ... other properties
    VpcConfig:
        VpcId: 
          Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${VpcStack}:VpcId
```

The VPC template at the TemplateURL looks like this excerpt:

```
  Resources:
    VPC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
      Properties:
        ... various properties    
   Outputs:
      VpcId:
        Value: !Ref VPC
        Export:
          Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}:VpcId
```

As you can see, I'm trying to import the VpcId from the nested stack.

```
VpcConfig:
   VpcId: 
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${VpcStack}:VpcId
```

However, this results in the following error:

> Template contains errors.: Template error: the attribute in
>   Fn::ImportValue must not depend on any resources, imported values, or
>   Fn::GetAZs

It makes sense that it is happening... VpcStack is indeed a resource.  But how do I avoid this?

Is this just a syntax thing, or do I need to actually structure my templates differently to pull this off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up keeping my existing structure and using this syntax:

```
VpcConfig:
    VpcId: 
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - VpcStack
        - Outputs.VpcId
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It worked. After 8 hrs found the solutions. :)